# Mysql + php value of columns in 4 divs

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to make this thing work but cant get it working.

So basically I have 2 tables I am fetching data from.

- 1st= playerinfo
- 2nd= playerstats
- From playerinfo I want to get the total value of column BankMoney
- From playerstats I want to get the total value of PlayerKills , DeathCount , AIKills

And make them show there.

[columns total here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E4Jg.png)

Here is my code

```html
<?php
$dbname = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbhost = ''; // localhost should suffice
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or exit(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or exit(mysql_error());

$loopResult = ''; // leave blank to start var for loop
$result = mysql_query("select * from playerstats,playerinfo limit 0,10") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$loopResult = '
<div class="container">
  
            <div class="section-header">
                <h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown">Tous les stats</h2>
                <p class="wow fadeInDown">Voici la totaliter des stats du serveur wasteland <b>En développement</b></p>
            </div>

            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="400ms" data-wow-delay="0ms">
                        <div class="business-stats" data-digit="'.$row['AIKills'].'" data-duration="1000"></div>
                        <strong>Joueurs</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="400ms" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                        <div class="business-stats" data-digit="'.$row['PlayerKills'].'" data-duration="1000"></div>
                        <strong>Victimes</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="400ms" data-wow-delay="200ms">
                        <div class="business-stats" data-digit="'.$row['BankMoney'].'" data-duration="1000"></div>
                        <strong>Argent totale</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="400ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        <div class="business-stats" data-digit="'.$row['DeathCount'].'" data-duration="1000"></div>
                        <strong>Deces</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  ';
}
echo $loopResult;
?>
```

If someone could assist me with this I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Table shemas

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PlayerStats`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PlayerStats`  
(
  `PlayerUID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `LastModified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `PlayerKills` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `AIKills` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `TeamKills` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `DeathCount` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ReviveCount` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `CaptureCount` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idx_PlayerStats_uniquePlayer` (`PlayerUID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PlayerStats_PlayerInfo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PlayerUID`)
    REFERENCES `PlayerInfo` (`UID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PlayerInfo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PlayerInfo` 
(
  `UID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Name` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL,
  `LastSide` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `BankMoney` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `BattlEyeGUID` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: And what is your question? What error message do you receive or unexpected behaviour do you encounter?

Comment: I do not get any errors, I just dont know how to get those data , I want the total of colums BankMoney , PlayerKills, AIKills, DeathCount but each separate

Comment: You are not able to write the sql for this data?, show your tables schema please.

Comment: Alright , I edited my post with the shemas

Comment: you know you can use <?php while(): ?> html stuff <?php endwhile; ?> to loop html content

Comment: Please refactor your code to use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension instead. The MySQL extension [has been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) since 2013 and has been dropped in PHP7 that was released earlier this week. So this code will not work on PHP7. Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use "Join" to get result for both tables for single user.

The query should be like

```
sql="select *, (PlayerKills+AIKills+TeamKills) as total_kill from playerinfo left join playerstats on playerstats.PlayerUID =  playerinfo.UID limit 0,10"
```

total_kill will have the total of all three values.

for more details of left join please check this http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx

Comment: got it working it shows data. but what i actualy want is show the total of the rows. lets say PlayerKill as 3 rows  , row1=7kill row2= 3 kill and row3 = 4 kills it would show 14 kills

Comment: if you want to add values of three columns then check my updated answer. and if you want to sum rows value then you can use sum function of my sql.

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to be showing the values in the html, only in the class - for example:

```
       <div class="business-stats" data-digit="'.$row['PlayerKills'].'" data-duration="1000">
       <strong>Victimes</strong>
```

Should be

```
       <div class="business-stats" data-digit="'.$row['PlayerKills'].'" data-duration="1000">'.$row['PlayerKills'].'</div>
       <strong>Victimes</strong>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Please scroll across to see the difference!

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, after grabbing the data from the db, pass it to a loop, in which you make sums in correspondent variables, after that just show the sums, for example:

```
Foreach ($arr as $row ){
  $sum_kills += $row ['kills'];
  $sum_fights += $row ['FIGHT']:
}
```